# How to create a numerical sequence that skips blank cells, based on adjacent cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA question, and can't seem to find a solution. So here goes...

I need to create a numerical sequence in column A, based on whether the cell next to it (in column B) has a number in it. If the cell in column B is blank, the cell in column A should continue the sequence. The numbers in column B are manually entered.

Right now I am using a formula (in this example, the formula is in A2):

=IF(B2,"", (ROW()-1))

This works well to get a sequence, and leave the cell blank if the adjacent cell contains a value, but because it's based on the row number, it doesn't give me what I need as it will only give me the row number -1.

I've started looking into VBA solutions, and what I have so far is this:

```
Sub AutoNumText()
lastRw = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 For nxtRw = 1 To lastRw
  If Range("B" & nxtRw) <> "" Then
   myNum = myNum + 1
   Range("A" & nxtRw) = myNum
     Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(myNum)
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

This isn't working either, and I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I can try next. Any suggestions?

*EDIT*

Here's an example of what the data should look like:

```
A   B

1   
    1
2   
    2
    2
3
```

Comment: If B2 is blank, should it continue the sequence from where it was interrupted or should the sequence start over?

Comment: @tigeravatar  the sequence should continue where it left off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one formula:

```
=IF(AND(ROW() = 1,B1=""),1,IF(B1="",MAX($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1))+1,""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
Sub AutoNumText()
lastRw = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For nxtRw = 1 To lastRw
    If Range("B" & nxtRw) = "" Then
        myNum = myNum + 1
        Range("A" & nxtRw) = myNum
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This only puts values in cells that have a value in the adjacent cell, so it's close, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, I've misunderstood your requirement. I see your example now. Answer changed.

Comment: This actually worked pretty well, but in larger sheets could get pretty heavy when converted to a function. The easiest solution seems to be what @ScottCraner posted.

Comment: Yes, you'd only want to run this once, or on occasion. Not set in a function that runs every recalc etc. @Scott's solution is elegant and often importantly, doesn't require macros enabled to work :)

Answer (score 0):

In **A1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="","",1)
```

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="","",1+MAX($A$1:A1))
```

and copy down:

[image]