# CountA function with exclusion of blank cells and certain text in Google Sheets unable to get serial numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am not getting correct serial numbers when I use OR function additionally in COUNTA function to add other exclusions. I am calculating this in Column A.
Where I am going wrong?
[COUNTA](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Or6KnzBrQ8RiSptwz64kgxh-v1kXpwzPhCHmwlWlruI/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to get the serial numbers excluding blank cells and certain text quoted in function.

Comment: After getting the serial numbers excluding blank cells, where would you like that to show, Is it in Col D? You have provided your initial output but what exactly is your expected Output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a sequence of numbers beginning with "1" and ignoring blanks and values "GHI" & "JKL"

Insert this formula in Cell A6, and copy down:

`=IF(AND(ROW() = 6,+if(isblank(B6),1,2)+IF(B6="GHI",1,2)+IF(B6="JKL",1,2)=6),1,IF(+if(isblank(B6),1,2)+IF(B6="GHI",1,2)+IF(B6="JKL",1,2)=6,MAX($D$6:INDEX($D:$D,ROW()-1))+1,""))`

---

**LOGIC**

The formula has two similar arms:

- **ARM#1** `IF(AND(ROW() = 6,` - applies to the first row.

  - If the row = 6 **AND** cell in Column B is not null AND <> "GHI" OR "JKL",
  - result: ID = 1
- **ARM#2** `IF(+if(isblank(B6),1,2)+IF(B6="GHI",1,2)+IF(B6="JKL",1,2)=6`

  - tests if the Column B cell isn't blank, = "GHI", or = "JKL"

    - assigns "1" is true and "2" if false
    - value = 6 means that the cell should get an id
  - `MAX($D$6:INDEX($D:$D,ROW()-1))+1,` -
  - result: returns the sequence number

The answer by @ScottCraner in [How to create a numerical sequence that skips blank cells, based on adjacent cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44138681/1330560) provides the basic logic for the formula.

---

**RESULTS**

[image: sample]

---